# I am getting in my DB the name of the variable but not the value of the variable

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to get data from a particular column from a text file and save this into a particular column in the database. The variable `NumberOfLine` is saved in the database, but I want the value of this variable which has to be some number (as string), I do not understand why it does not work. Do you have any suggestions?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class TxtFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try{  
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaDB","acc:#####","pass:#####"); 

                System.out.print("Successful connection with MySQL!");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\lotto.txt"));

             String line;
                String NumberOfLine = "";
                String SecondNumber = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] splited = line.split("\\s");

                    //take value of  column 4 from txt file
                    NumberOfLine = splited[3];

                    //save the current number into the DB
                    Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
                    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `kanat`(Number1) VALUE ('"+NumberOfLine+"')");
                }
                br.close();
                con.close(); 

                System.out.println("Finished! ");

            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("No success! " + e);
                }  
            }  

}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a (fake) sample of the file you're reading there? Just to check :)

Comment: Are you sure that your quotes are all correct (although they look fine in this snippet)?  There is some slightly tricky quoting going on there, and the fact that you are inserting the string "NumberOfLine" instead of the variable makes me think there is some error in the quotes.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but use a prepared statement.

Comment: Please show how do you check what is actually written to the database?

Comment: I am not really sure about the quotes I tried with different quotes but it does the same. I added photo Alfabravo*

Comment: lexocore, what do you mean how I check the db? I just open the WorkBench and refresh the table and I see that in the Number1 column the values are only the name of the variable NumberOfLine

Comment: My suggestion (the question asked for suggestions) would be use a prepared statement with bind placeholders. [LittleBobbyTables](https://xkcd.com/327/) warns that the pattern in this code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection  or, to put it another way,  why are we debugging code that we already know is broken? let's do it right. then we'll talk about problems with that code.

Comment: Can you show the select statement you are using to actually fetch data from DB?

Comment: @Patrahi Please use `@username` to get people notified of your reply.

Comment: @Vooza, I do not understand what you are asking, sorry.

Comment: Same as lexicore actually, but you already answered that. Can you show  how the table is defined? Does the column have default value? Also in the input file are you using tabs or spaces? How many?

Comment: @Patrahi The `Number1` gets written to the DB from the first (header) line of your txt file. But there should be actual values written from the following lines. At least I can't spot an error which would prevent it. So *maybe* values are actually are in the database. Therefore I wonder how exactly do you check it. Does the workbench show you the complete contents of the table?

Comment: @Patrahi Your comments make an impression that may be you don't exactly know how to work with the database. Please don't take it personally, but this leaves some room for doubt, may be actual values do actually get inserted into the table.

Comment: @lexicore When I open workbench I am seeing that in the column the value is exactly NumberOfLine and the other columns are empty and it is written NULL.

Comment: @lexicore If I understand correctly he is saying that he opens up a MySQL client and looks at the table and sees the string "NumberOfLine" written a bunch of times in the "Number1" column.  To me that is a clear indication that there is an error with the way the INSERT string is being constructed.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese - Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese The value simply comes from the first line in the txt file. It does not indicate an error in the INSERT statement per se.

Comment: @lexicore I think that is incorrect. The string "NumberOfLine" does not appear anywhere in the text file.  That String is the name of the variable in the code.  As far as I can tell, the only way the String "NumberOfLine" can appear in the DB is if the insert statement is being improperly constructed.

Comment: So when I debug, I am seeing the value when I hover over the veriable NumberOfLine, but the value is not saved.

Comment: If we don't want the value 'Number1' stored in the database, it seems like we should skip over the heading line in the file. The code appears to be performing an `INSERT` with 'Number1' provided as value. I don't have an explanation as to why subsequent lines aren't also being processed/inserted. `readline` breaks at \n, \r or \r\n. Seems like some simple debugging would be to println the contents of NumberOfLine prior to reach INSERT.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese - your logic is good but check the statement where do you think it can be wrong:     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `kanat`(Number1) VALUE ('"+NumberOfLine+"')");

Comment: But that whole business of string concatenation to create a SQL statement is just *broken*. Why are we spending *any* time debugging code that is using a pattern that is well known to be VULNERABLE to SQL Injection. It makes little sense.

Comment: @spencer7593 - the point here is not about SQL injection or Security and so on... the point is to copy from txt to DB some information and to make it works.

Comment: @Patrahi I agree with spencer7593. Please rewrite this using a prepared statement first, and then - if the problem still persists - it might make sense actually debugging it.

Comment: @Patrahi: you're right, it's not just about security and SQL Injection. The point is why are we spending time on code patterns that are known to be broken. Why not spend the time working on code patterns that are best practice, are known to work, and that softare professionals will be able to assist you with. There are good reasons (other than security) that best practice coding patterns are the best practice... and one of those is that its just easier to spot problems and debug. Get in the liferaft, dude! Don't dangle your legs in shark infested water clinging to debris that is going to sink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSERT` statement is malformed. The keyword is `VALUES` not `VALUE`.

This could easily be debugged, by outputting the SQL text, and taking it to another client.

Too much work is being done in one line there; and the work that is being done is *broken* in that it's vulnerable to SQL Injection.

There's no need here to use string concatenation to dynamically prepare the SQL text.  And there's no need to repeatedly churn through creating and recreating the sql and the statement ...

```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO `kanat`(Number1) VALUES ( ? )";
  PreparedStatement ps = null;

  try {

     ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

     while( ... ) {
        String numberOfLine = ...

        ps.setString(1, numberOfLine);
        ps.executeUpdate();

     }
  } catch (SQLException e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
      if (ps != null) {
          ps.close();
      }
  }
```

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If the objective is to simply load new rows into a table, reading one "column" from space delimited .txt file, personally, I wouldn't futz with writing inefficient Java code, processing RBAR (row by agonizing row).

I'd just use the builtin MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement and blow the whole file in one transaction.

Something like this:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/tmp/myfile.txt" 
 INTO TABLE mytable
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES
 ( @d1
 , @d2
 , @d3
 , @d4
 , @d5
 , @d5
 , @d6
 ) 
 SET mycol = TRIM(BOTH FROM @d4)
 ;
```

If it's an unusually large file that I need to load, since I don't want "Hugh Jass" transactions  blowing out the innodb system tablespace (space I can't get back), I'd either split the file (OS `split` command), or male use of the percona toolkit `pt-fifo-split` to split the file into a pipe on the fly.

Comment: @Patrahi:  saying "*it does not work*" is a nearly useless description of the behavior that is observed. Is it throwing compiler errors? Compiling successfully but throwing an execution error? Appear to run successfully but results are unexpected? Throw us a bone, dude! "does not work" conveys very little useful information.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Note that this code example does not address the current contents of the kanat table... which was previously reported to contain numerous rows with Number1 values "NumberOfLine". Those rows are still going to be in the table, until they are removed. The code in this example performs INSERT statements. (The code shown in this answer is *not* compiled or tested. And obviously, the bit about reading lines and getting a value assigned to numberOfLine is omitted (represented by three dots ... )

Comment: the behaviour of the code is the same when I hover over the ps.executeUpdate();  I can see the VALUE that I want to save in the DB but when I open the DB it is saved only the name of the variable as before.

Comment: I found it now, when I debug it that for 1 loop it inserts 1000 rows with the name of the variable! how is that possible?

Comment: @Patrahi: Have you *removed* those rows from the table? If those rows are in the table, they are going to stay there until they are deleted, or the table is truncated. (I think you may be looking at row from previous efforts, and thinking that those were just inserted by the latest execution.)

Comment: @Patrahi: I suggest you add some code to produce some debugging output, as a rudimentary example `System.out.println(" numberOfLine = " + numberOfLine);` immediately before executing the SQL statement.

Comment: Hi guys thank you very much I was able to solve the problem basically, I used the code of @spencer7593 and I created new table in the DB. And it works now I do not know why it did not work. Maybe my code works too, I have to try it, maybe the whole problem was from WorkBench...